# Why was the Santa hat removed from VSCode insider builds?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Where did the Santa hat go in VSCode insider builds? I have a custom plugin for VS Code where when I click on the Santa hat it directs me to the [Santa Tracker](https://santatracker.google.com/) by google. I did this for my kids for Christmas eve to get them to bed early. Does anyone know why Microsoft removed it from Visual Studio Code Insider builds? And how can I add it back?

Relevant info: 
Version: 1.42.0-insider

Answer (score 2):

It was removed due to [a GitHub issue on the repository for VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87268).

Comment: Riiight...How did Microsoft miss the fact this was someone who was trolling?......